# Maximum value of the microcanonical distribution for the finite 2D Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

Here's an interesting combinatorial problem relating to the two-dimensional *N* x *N* Ising model, whose energy is given by $$E=-\sum_{(i,j)pairs} Js_is_j, $$where the value of nearest-neighbor cells are $s_i,s_j=\pm1.$

The microcanonical distribution $\Omega(E,M)$ is the number of state configurations corresponding to the pairings of energy E and the number of positive-value cells $M=\sum_i s_i$. The contours of nonzero $\Omega(E,M)$ values on the (*E*,*M*) grid have roughly the shape of a rocket ship with a broad mid-section (see figure below).

Some of the landmarks of the "rocket" are as follows: the legs of the rocket ship arise from the lower corners of the grid: $(E=-2N^2J,M=\pm N^2)$ (all cells with same value), with multiplicity $\Omega=1$. The ship's apex (for even values of *N*) corresponds to a checkerboard pattern with grid position $(E=+2N^2J,M=0)$ and multiplicity $\Omega=2$. The "thruster" at the bottom midline of the rocketship at grid position $(E=-2N^2J+NJ,M=0)$, corresponds to the minimum energy configuration for $M=0$ (straight line separating phases of different values) with multiplicity $\Omega=2N$.

[image: Ising micronanonical distribution]

My question is: what is $\Omega_{max}$, which occurs at the grid position $(E=0,M=0)$, i.e. the exact center of the grid?

I've done some brute-force computations using a computer and can provide the following values for smaller grids: $\Omega_{max}$(2 x 2) = 4; $\Omega_{max}$(4 x 4) = 4356; and $\Omega_{max}$(6 x 6) = 1744323016.

I'd like to know the general formula for $\Omega_{max}$ for any even value of *N*, if it exists. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Below are the results for grids as large as 14 x 14 using Monte Carlo simulation. The blue line is the results of the simulation. The other lines are approximate values based on empiric formulas supplied by @AlekseyDruggist (see comments).

[image: Plot for Wmax]

Comment: And what about  blue areas around "the legs"? As far as I understand, these are "forbidden states" with $\Omega=0$ ?

Comment: Aleksey, that's correct. Allowed states are found only within the raised areas of the plot, with the most probable state located in the center.

Comment: @ DSigg, Obviously, the upper bound for $\Omega_{max}$  will be $2^{N^2}$, it will also be asymptotics $\Omega_{max}$ for large N. It is interesting that for the given values (2x2, 4x4, 6x6), the estimate $2^{N^2-N}$ seems to be more appropriate, although I have no any  physical rationale.

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist, I'm working on Monte Carlo simulations to solve the problem for N larger than 6. I'll let you know if your approximate formula holds true.

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist, using Monte Carlo sampling with importance sampling, I extended the solution to grids as large as 14 x 14. The trick is to find a histogram that closely matches the one that is being sampled. I did this by horizontally rescaling the solution from a smaller grid and using your formula as a vertical scaling factor.

Comment: It's  very interesting, but as to $2^{N^2}$ this is not an empiric formula, it is a pure combinatorics, the total number of spin configurations. A more "subtle" upper bound $\dfrac{N^2!}{(N^2/2)!(N^2/2)!}$ - the number of spin configurations for fixed number  $N^2/2$  of upward spins. It is also a the greatest term in the expansion $(1 + 1)^{N^2}$